# Weird java.sql.SQLException error

Tags: java, sql, dbase

I have a weird issue and most the stuff I seem to find on the web is referring to a driver or connection problem...

I am parsing threw a dBASE table to get some id numbers:

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
Connection cnxn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:dBASE Files;DefaultDir=\"C:\"");
Statement stmt = cnxn.createStatement();
command = "SELECT * FROM table";
ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery(command);
while (result.next()) {
    System.out.println(result.getInt(1));
}
```

The result that i get in the console is

```
1
2
3
4
...
1312
1313
1314
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid string or buffer length
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLGetDataString(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.getDataString(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.getString(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.getString(Unknown Source)
```

the line that generated the error is:

```
System.out.println(result.getInt(1));
```

Since i am getting a result out of it, I don't think it's a connection error or a driver one. I looked at the table and I don't seem to have anything wrong with the row 1315, i tried deleting it and nothing. Btw the table used has 2376 rows.

I have tried with another table with a different length and I also get the error after 417 rows.

Just in case it helps I am on windows 7, 64 bit, the tables are dBASE IV.

Thx in advance!

Comment: If you post the entire stack trace someone might be able to explain the error.

Comment: That is a weird error.  It looks like first there is some kind of error with the field, but then, when the dBase driver tries to create the SQL Exception, there is a second problem and the ODBC driver manager throws an exception.  This indicates that at least the second problem is a bug in the dBase driver.  Try doing a select id from table and see if it still happens.

Comment: I think it's SQL Server write ? 
because i didn't see this on MS Access .

Comment: It's dBase ... as he stated and as that connect string clearly shows. He's using the ODBC driver to access it.

Comment: Also, try where id > 1314.  If you query for one field and it errors on the second record it's a much more narrow problem, and knowing that might be helpful.  Alternatively, it might not happen until a later record, and that would be useful to know.

Comment: I added the full stack trace, I tried a SELECT TOP 1000 and it returned without any errors. I doubt it would be a bad line since I have this issue with multiple table that have no problem querying with VFP or other dBASE application.

Comment: I also was able to select the line 1310 to 1320 separately.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea still.  How about selecting 1,314 records from the table, but with a different range (for example, rows 1,000 -> 2,313)?  I am wondering if the error still occur.